# How to send mail with a Subject using a Mailto URL?

Tags: html, uri, mailto

I need to make a `Mailto link` to my website which is suppose to contain either the product name or the product page URL in the `subject section`. How can I do it?
Exp: When you get an email through `eBay` about a product you are selling or buying, you automatically know what product that email is about by seeing the product name in the subject section.
How can i do this?

Comment: Frank, that subject line really could have been better.

Answer (score 61):

```
<a href="mailto:example@foo.com?subject=hello world">Email Me!</a>
```

Internet Archive:

- [Set up an HTML mailto form without a back-end script](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/set-up-an-html-mailto-form-without-a-back-end-script/)
- [HTML Mailto Attribute and Tips](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/html_mailto_attribute_html_tips.php3)
- [HTML Mailto Tips and Tricks](http://www.angelfire.com/dc/html-webmaster/mailto.htm)
- [Mailto Syntax](http://web.archive.org/web/20111014035719/http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html)

Related Stackoverflow Questions:

- [Avoiding the Mailto Annoyance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891131/how-to-avoid-the-mailto-annoyance/891143)
- [Best way to obfuscate an e-mail address on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748780/best-way-to-obfuscate-an-e-mail-address-on-a-website/)
- [Effective method to hide email from spam bots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483212/effective-method-to-hide-email-from-spam-bots)
- [What are some ways to protect emails on websites from spambots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308772/what-are-some-ways-to-protect-emails-on-websites-from-spambots)

Comment: @sur007 Thank you for pointing this out. I was able to point them to a cached copy in the wayback machine. Thanks!

Comment: wlecome, My Pleasure.

Answer (score 11):

I've run into problems with this before when I didn't url encode the value, so I would suggest (using lc's example):

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=This+Is+My+Product">
```

or

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=This%20Is%20My%20Product">
```

Answer (score 5):

[This page [Link Dead]](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html) outlines the syntax of mailto URIs:

- Address message to multiple recipients

  ```
  ,   (comma separating e-mail addresses)
  ```
- Add entry in the "Subject" field

  ```
  subject=Subject Field Text
  ```
- Add entry in the "Copy To" or "CC" field

  ```
  cc=id@internet.node
  ```
- Add entry in the "Blind Copy To" or "BCC" field

  ```
  bcc=id@internet.node
  ```
- Add entry in the "Body" field

  ```
  body=Your message here

  Within the body use "%0A" for a new line,
  use "%0A%0A" for a new line preceded by a blank line (paragraph),
  ```

What you are looking for is:

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=This Is My Product">
```

Note, it's probably a good idea to URL encode the spaces with either a `+` or a `%20`:

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=This+Is+My+Product">
```

Comment: Link produces a 404.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="mailto:stefan.mai@example.com?subject=YourSubjectHere">Try This</a>
```

If you want something more advanced, you're going to have to code it from scratch (or use someone else's script). Try looking into PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to set subject, body, cc, bcc

```html
<p>HI <a href = "mailto:venkateshkarni1996@gmail.com?subject=Hello&body= Have a good day!&cc=add here cc email&bcc=add here bcc email">venky!</a></p>
```