# E-mail Form within Cordova?

Tags: php, html, cordova, email

I am currently making an app using Cordova. However, I would like to make a e-mail form that the end user can use to send an song request to a specified e-mail. My question is if this is possible considering that there would have to be a PHP handler in the mix. If anyone knows please let me know. BTW: I am using MDL for the UI and I don't know how that would behave with the  tag.

Comment: PHP is executed on the server side and Cordova is frontend are totally differents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Email using phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040371/sending-email-using-phonegap)