# Opening Email app when click on "email" link

Tags: javascript, html

how can i allow a clickable "EMAIL" text in html to automatically open some email app or site inserting the clicked email in the " To: " form?

Comment: `<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>` should do it.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [How to send mail with a Subject using a Mailto URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1093925/691711).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use mailto links:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">Email Us</a>
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the mailto URL format, like so:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com">email</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the following URL format

```
<a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=someone@somewhere.com"                                  target="_blank">someone@somewhere.com</a>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.